# How to Upgrade Linux Kernel 4.0.2?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I followed the steps for Updating the Kernel 4.0.2 from the source  [How To Install/Upgrade Linux Kernel](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/05/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-0-2-in-linux.html) and finally got this error.

```
    root@surfer:/home/algosig# sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.0.2*.deb linux-image-4.0.2*.deb
    (Reading database ... 621608 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.0.2-040002_4.0.2-040002.201505081529_all.deb ...
    Unpacking linux-headers-4.0.2-040002 (4.0.2-040002.201505081529) over (4.0.2-040002.201505081529) ...
    Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.0.2-040002-generic_4.0.2-040002.201505081529_i386.deb ...
    Unpacking linux-headers-4.0.2-040002-generic (4.0.2-040002.201505081529) over (4.0.2-040002.201505081529) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.0.2-040002-generic.
    Preparing to unpack linux-image-4.0.2-040002-generic_4.0.2-040002.201505081529_i386.deb ...
    Done.
    Unpacking linux-image-4.0.2-040002-generic (4.0.2-040002.201505081529) ...
    dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'linux-image-4.0.2-040002-generic_4.0.2-040002.201505081529_i386.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
    dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal bzip2 read error: 'UNEXPECTED_EOF'
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
    dpkg: error processing archive linux-image-4.0.2-040002-generic_4.0.2-040002.201505081529_i386.deb (--install):
     cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.0.2-040002-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.2-040002-generic.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
    Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.0.2-040002-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.2-040002-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-extlinux 4.0.2-040002-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.2-040002-generic
    P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic...
    P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic...
    P: Installing debian theme... done.
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.0.2-040002-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.2-040002-generic
    Setting up linux-headers-4.0.2-040002 (4.0.2-040002.201505081529) ...
    Setting up linux-headers-4.0.2-040002-generic (4.0.2-040002.201505081529) ...
    Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.0.2-040002-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.2-040002-generic
    ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.0.2-040002-generic is not supported
    Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.0.2-040002-generic (i686)
    Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log for more information.
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-4.0.2-040002-generic_4.0.2-040002.201505081529_i386.deb
```

And This was the log file:

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-4.3.10 for kernel 4.0.2-040002-generic (i686)
Sun May 10 18:54:43 NPT 2015
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.2-040002-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/alloc-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/initterm-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/memobj-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/mpnotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/powernotification-r0drv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/assert-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/initterm-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memuserkernel-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mpnotification-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/process-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semevent-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semeventmulti-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semfastmutex-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/semmutex-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/spinlock-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/thread-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/thread2-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/threadctxhooks-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/time-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/timer-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/generic/semspinmutex-r0drv-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/alloc/alloc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/checksum/crc32.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/checksum/ipv4.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/checksum/ipv6.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/err/RTErrConvertFromErrno.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/err/RTErrConvertToErrno.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/log.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/logellipsis.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/logrel.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/logrelellipsis.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/logcom.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/logformat.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/RTAssertMsg1Weak.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2Add.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2AddWeak.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2AddWeakV.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2Weak.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/RTAssertMsg2WeakV.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/assert.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/handletable.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/handletablectx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/misc/thread.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/RTStrCopy.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/RTStrCopyEx.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/RTStrCopyP.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/RTStrNCmp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/RTStrNLen.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/stringalloc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/strformat.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/strformatrt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/strformattype.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/strprintf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/string/strtonum.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/table/avlpv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/common/time/time.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/RTLogWriteDebugger-r0drv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTAssertShouldPanic-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTLogWriteStdErr-stub-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTLogWriteStdOut-stub-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTLogWriteUser-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTMpGetArraySize-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTMpGetCoreCount-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTSemEventWait-2-ex-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTSemEventWaitNoResume-2-ex-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTSemEventMultiWait-2-ex-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTSemEventMultiWaitNoResume-2-ex-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/RTTimerCreate-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/errvars-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/mppresent-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/generic/uuid-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/VBox/log-vbox.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/math/gcc/divdi3.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/math/gcc/moddi3.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/math/gcc/qdivrem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/math/gcc/udivdi3.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/math/gcc/umoddi3.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxdrv/vboxdrv.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c: In function ‘vboxNetAdpOsCreate’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c:186:48: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
                            vboxNetAdpNetDevInit);
                                                ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c:184:15: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     pNetDev = alloc_netdev(sizeof(VBOXNETADPPRIV),
               ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c:184:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c: At top level:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c:159:13: warning: ‘vboxNetAdpNetDevInit’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void vboxNetAdpNetDevInit(struct net_device *pNetDev)
             ^
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp] Error 2
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.0.2-040002-generic'
```

Can somebody illustrate the step wise process to upgrade the linux Kernel?

Comment: You likely have a **corrupted** *.deb* file. Redownload them all.

Comment: And the second log appears to be you trying to build the kernel and it fails because the kernel you are trying to build is broken.  You will have to report that to wherever you got that source code.

Comment: From what is in the log file I'd say that virtualbox has trouble with the newest kernels and needs to be updated and/or adapted. Also "dkms" seems troublesome - can't tell what that depends on - check what has changed in that regard with the new kernel.

Comment: It is failing because the Virtualbok kernel module is failing to build. Remove it and use KVM =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very useful script called *kernel-update*. It is in portuguese but it is very simple. First, open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and install Lynx (text browser):

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

then run this command to download the script:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwkeja3cijdbk7l/kernel-update
```

Change its permission with chmod:

```
chmod +x kernel-update
```

Now you can run this script whenever you want to update your kernel with the command

```
sudo ./kernel-update
```

It is in Brazilian Portuguese, but...

1) Click A to verify/install a new kernel

2) Click B to delete older kernels

3) Click Q to exit.

Well, do not forget to run in a terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

to update linux image and

```
sudo update-grub
```

so GRUB will recognize the new Kernel.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:** I got this tutorial from [this](http://www.diolinux.com.br/2015/04/como-atualizar-kernel-para-a-ultima-versao-no-ubuntu.html) website.

Comment: For starters: Sorry to disappoint you, but the script is not complete, `update-grub` and `update-initramfs -u` are missing. There is more to this task than just compile and place it in the right place. There has been changes that requires adaptation elsewhere too.

Comment: Well, the script downloads and installs the kernel, the GRUB part is not included because you have to consider that GRUB is not default in some linux distros, and the user might want to change the boot manager, that is why kernel-update does not include update-grub. And update-initramfs -u is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Yes, but this is an Ubuntu specific forum, and for Ubuntu at least `update-grub` is required (I actually believe it runs update-initramfs 'magically').

Comment: Yes, this forum is ubuntu specific, but the script is not. And as I said (and as you should know), Ubuntu is a free OS and people can choose their own boot manager. I cannot simply say "run update-grub and everything is done".

Comment: Have a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack - you will hopefully realize that installing a newer kernel than what is 'supported' may not be as simple as the above implies. An update from 3.13 to 3.16 for Ubuntu 14.04.2 apparently requires updated mesa and xorg. Expect more to be required for kernels beyond 3.16

Comment: Did you take a look at the script? Well, I just answered algosig's question, how to upgrade linux kernel. That's all.

Comment: The answer might be correct, but it is incomplete.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit it.