# Wireless not working after installing Kernel 4.0.5 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless

I just followed this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/621890/411609)

What should be the right thing to do? 
Revert to old kernel?

- Here's the [log by the way](https://gist.github.com/RoldanLT/4663c4f22e28200374f0)
- This is Acer V5-552G by the way ussing AMD A-105757M CPU.

When I do:

```
$ sudo modprobe wl
```

Result is:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
```

When I run this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Edit: Just reverted back to Kernel 3.19 and I got this:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280


04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` I believe your wireless can be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Added now. But I'm on Kernel 3.19 now.

Comment: No problem.  I undeleted my answer by the way.  I will keep looking into this for you.  If I find a solution, I will definitely let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device requires bcmwl-kernel-source.The version in the repositories doesn't build correctly for kernels 4.0 and later, as you've seen. With a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install git-buildpackage
mkdir bcmwl-ubuntu
cd bcmwl-ubuntu
git clone https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu.git bcmwl-ubuntu-master
cd bcmwl-ubuntu-master
gbp buildpackage -b -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-longsleep0_amd64.deb
```

The kernel module will build automatically for all your installed kernel
versions with the help of DKMS and apply patching as required.

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: I got an error? https://gist.github.com/RoldanLT/989c34e0a05dd34b138f

Comment: Please try:`sudo apt-get install dh-modaliases` and try again.

Comment: I also run: sudo apt-get install debhelper
To make the build successful.

Comment: When I run this command: sudo apt-get install git-buildpackage. 
I installed a lot of dependencies. Now I have wireless working fine.
Can I remove it? and all it's dependencies?
To list them all, here it is: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RoldanLT/c9ad6f735713499f2766/raw/ce99f64b3ab4c96819dd27e55b1cf30f57298df0/gistfile1.txt

Comment: I am not at all sure that you can and still get the updates installed automatically. As they take up fairly little space, I'd leave them. I'm very glad the wireless is working.

Answer (score 2):

Less headache now as I got PPA/pre-built packages from https://launchpad.net/~longsleep/+archive/ubuntu/bcmwl.

So easy to install :)

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/bcmwl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Answer (score 0):

To install the older `vivid` kernel, open a terminal window and type in:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid`

after it is installed, reboot your system by holding down shift, then select advanced boot options, and select the 3.19.x-xx kernel.  Once booted in, you can remove the 4.0.x kernel by typing in the following from a terminal window:

`sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.0* linux-image-4.0*`

when it removes the 4.0.x kernel, it should run the grub-update on its own, so when you reboot, it should only boot to the 3.19.x-xx kernel.

To install the 4.0.x kernels, it is usually best to get them from here:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

then when you want to install them, open a terminal window.  Go to your /tmp folder, then run `wget` to download them.

`wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0.5-wily/name_of_kernel.deb`

when downloading them, choose the headers generic, headers all, and image generic.  I have posted the names below:

```
linux-headers-4.0.5-040005-generic_4.0.5-040005.201506061639_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.0.5-040005_4.0.5-040005.201506061639_all.deb
linux-image-4.0.5-040005-generic_4.0.5-040005.201506061639_amd64.deb
```

once they are downloaded, from the /tmp folder, all you have to type in to install them is

`sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb`

that way you also keep your 3.19.x-xx kernel installed as well so that you can fall back on it if the 4.0.5 kernel fails somehow.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-vivid

Comment: I think I have it still installed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RoldanLT/7c4e5b44301cc6e274ef/raw/589fc9e2e31642273c992cccd2cf2c1a604fe894/gistfile1.txt

Comment: You do have it installed.  Looks like the repository pointing to the kernel may not be setup.  Boot your host back to the 3.19.x-xx kernel.

Comment: So there's no solution on fixing Wireless problem? With Kernel 4.05.

Comment: @RoldanLT I am wondering if it is missing parts of the kernel, or if there is a patch that needs to be done on the wireless.  I have found that some NVIDIA drivers needed a patch to accept above 3.19 kernels.  Do you know if the instructions that you followed before downloaded the three .deb files I listed here?

Comment: @chili555 added this to the wrong section.  I am answering, not asking.  :)

Comment: @RoldanLT I am looking into if the wireless driver can be compiled into the 4.0.5 kernel.